# Adding memoization for this divide and conquer solution

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, memoization, divide-and-conquer

i'm trying to solve the following question

Q: Max profit in K transactions, i.e have to buy and sell a stock given an array of stock prices on different days.

For input [5, 11, 3, 50, 60, 90,] the algorithm should buy at 5 and sell at 11, then buy at 3 and sell at 90 for K=2 transactions giving an answer of 93 (11-3=6 and 90-3=87, 6+87=93).

I have come up with a divide and conquer algorithm, but unable to figure out how to add memoization to this. I tried just using an array called profits but its not working.

I can use some help, Thank you!

```
def max_profits(prices, index, profit, transactions, maxTransactions, isBought):

    if(transactions == maxTransactions):
        return profit

    if(index > len(prices) - 1):
        return profit

    buy = 0
    sell = 0
    if(not isBought):
        buy = max_profits(prices, index + 1, profit - prices[index], transactions, maxTransactions, True)
    else:
        sell = max_profits(prices, index + 1, profit + prices[index], transactions + 1, maxTransactions, False)
    dont_sell_or_buy = max_profits(prices, index + 1, profit, transactions, maxTransactions, isBought)

    return max(buy, sell, dont_sell_or_buy)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    maxTransactions = int(input())
    inp = list(map(int, input().split()))
    print(max_profits(inp, 0, 0, 0, maxTransactions, False))
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile VScode, its not an IDE exactly though

Comment: I ask because my IDE would have pointed out the redundant parentheses and variable names. The latter should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.